# Order of SELECT statements using the UNION function?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, union

How do I order the select statements using the UNION function?
I want the output to be the order the select statements. EG T1 then T2 then T3.

**Query:**

```
select 'T1' as Table, sum(col1) from table1
group by 'T1'
UNION
select 'T2' as Table, sum(col2) from table2
group by 'T1'
UNION
select 'T3' as Table, sum(col3) from table3
group by 'T1'

order by 'T1', 'T2', 'T3'
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

| Table | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | 45 |
| T2 | 90 |
| T3 | 71 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an auxiliary column for sorting as follows:

with using CTE

```
With CTE As (
select 0 as Sort, 'T1' as "Table", sum(col1) as "Sum" from table1
UNION
select 1 as Sort, 'T2' as "Table", sum(col2) as "Sum" from table2
UNION
select 2 as Sort, 'T3' as "Table", sum(col3) as "Sum" from table3
)
Select "Table", "Sum"
From CTE
Order by Sort
```

It should work also using a subquery, since subquery scan will be applied to the sorted input.

```
Select "Table", "Sum"
From (
select 0 as Sort, 'T1' as "Table", sum(col1) as "Sum" from table1
UNION
select 1 as Sort, 'T2' as "Table", sum(col2) as "Sum" from table2
UNION
select 2 as Sort, 'T3' as "Table", sum(col3) as "Sum" from table3
Order by Sort   
) As T
```

Comment: Note that in standard SQL (and Postgres) square brackets are invalid in an identifier (they are used for accessing array elements). To use reserved keywords, you need to use double quotes in (standard) SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the remark. Didn't notice a postgresql tag. I've edited query.

Comment: Thanks! This has worked. Is there a way to do without using a CTE?

Comment: You are welcome. It should work also using a subquery, since subquery scan will be applied to the sorted input.